# Coordinates of the intersection of two tangents to a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, analytic-geometry

Let $A = (x_A, y_A)$ and $B = (x_B, y_B)$. Let $\gamma$ be a circumference of radius $r$, centered in $(0, 0)$; $A$ and $B$ lie outside of $\gamma$, and on the same side of some line $L$ through the center of $\gamma$.

> Make tangents from $A$ and $B$ to $\gamma$. These tangents intersect in a point $C$, on the same side. What are the coordinates of $C$?

[image]
*In green, you can see the tangents from $A$ and from $B$, which intersect in $C$.*

I could find a solution by finding the equation of each tangent, and then finding their intersections. However, such a solution involves manipulating quite a few parametric polynomials, which takes a long time and is rather inelegant. Is there a simpler solution relying upon geometrical theorems?

Comment: If $A,B$ are on the circle there are only two tangents, so only one intersection. However if $A,B$ are each not on the circle (and outside it) there are two tangents from $A$ and also two from $B,$ so picking one of each gives *four* intersection points, except in some special cases where some tangent from $A$ is parallel to one from $B$.

Comment: @coffeemath: whoops! I implicitly meant "the two intersections closest to the circle". I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: A clearer definition of what you mean may be: Suppose $A,B$ are outside the circle and on the same side of some line $L$ through the circle center. Then the tangents which meet the circle on that side of $L$ are the ones you want to intersect. But even that would mean there is only one point of intersection, not two as your $A,A'$ notation seems to indicate. [Oh I just noted, maybe you want the two on that side of $L$ and also the two on the remote side of $L$, which *would* give two intersections.]

Comment: I'll go for @coffeemath's definition, all I really needed was one point of intersection - specifically, the closest one.

Comment: According to the figure drawn, can we assume (1) the tangent through B is horizontal; and (2) A is at (a, 0)?

Comment: @Mick The condition that the tangent through $B$ is horizontal can be obtained by an initial rotation if necessary. But then to be general $A$ might not have its $y$ coordinate $0$, although as you say the diagram suggests that.

Comment: For some reason I don't see your figure. I'm using Firefox 31.0.

Comment: @AméricoTavares: you can find the image at http://i.stack.imgur.com/kCgRf.png.

Comment: GiulioMuscarello Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with we may assume the circle $C$, center $(0,0),$ has radius $1$ (divide all coordinates by the circle radius, then remultiply at the end).
Rewrite each of $A,B$ in polar coordinates as $(r_a,\theta_a),\ (r_b,\theta_b).$ For each of $A,B$ there are then two points on $C$ where the tangents from $A$ or $B$ meet $C$, say they are at $t_a,t_b$ in the sense that their coordinates are e.g. $P(t_a)=(\cos(t_a),\sin(t_a))$ for $A$ and similarly for $B.$ The values for these $t$ are
$$t_a=\theta_a \pm \cos^{-1}(1/r_a) \tag{1}$$
and similarly for $t_b$, as may be seen from a right triangle with one vertex at $A$, another at $P(t_a)$ and the third at the origin $O=(0,0).$ [right angle is at $P(t_a).$]
The $\pm$ choice reflects which of the two tangents from $A$ one wants to use.

Once we have made choices for which tangent to use at each point, which amounts to choosing the sign in $(1),$ we have specific values for the angles $t_a$ and $t_b.$ Then the polar coordinates for the intersection point of the two tangents has its angle as $(t_a+t_b)/2$ and its radius as $\sec[(t_a-t_b)/2].$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $L$ be the tangent line from $A(s, t)$ to the circle (γ) touching it at $T$ (and also $T’$ too) with slope = $m$ and angle of inclination = $θ$.

Equation of $L$ is given by $y – t = m(x – s)$

Solving $L$ and (γ), with the added condition of equal roots for tangency, we found $m$ (after choosing the right one) and hence $θ$.

Let $L$ cuts the $x$-axis at $A’(a, 0)$, for some $a$ to be determined.

Then, $0 – t = m(a – s)$ giving $a = \frac {–t}{m} + s$.

In the figure, $\angle BCO = \angle A'CO = \angle COA’ = (0.5)θ$

Note also that $⊿A’OC$ is isosceles with $A’O = A’C = a$. Together with $\angle CA’O  = π – θ$, $OC$ can be found by cosine law.

∴ $C$ is located at $(OC, (0.5)θ)$ in polar co-ordinates.

Note-1. According to the question, m will never be zero, otherwise there will be infinitely many or no C.

Note-2. If θ = 90 degrees, things should be treated separately but then (0.5)θ = 45 degrees.

Note-3. If A is on the x-axis, the proof can be further simplified. I think, through simple adjustments, such assumption is allowable.